# USB only work on BIOS

Tags: laptop, usb, bios, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 700-15isk, my problem is that the USB ports only work on bios, but in the OS appears error code 10 (windows 10) or I can't even try ubuntu. I think the problem might be the bios version but I'm not sure because I already try to update it, it kinda work but in it got installed rarely fast and in when it has to shutdown or reboot didn't happen anything.

For now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try any Linux live CD, then try those commands:
`dmesg | grep -iE -C 3 'EHCI|OHCI|UHCI'`
and `lsusb` . You can paste the output here.

You can this way determine if it's hardware related issue.

Comment: I can't copy the command, this symbol "|". I'm assuming that your are referring to GNU GRUB. In the line "linux           /casper/vmlinuz....." between "quiet" and "splash"